# Android ArrayAdapter NullPointer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, contacts, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to make an app that will use an AutoCompleteTextView and read from your contacts depending on what you type, so it doesn't have to deal with a huge array. Unfortunately the ArrayAdapter doesn't seem to like me.
Here is my code for it:

```
    private void updateAdapter(String[] nC)
{

    autoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, nC);

    autoText.setAdapter(autoAdapter);
}
```

This throws this:

```
WARN/Filter(16767): An exception occured during performFiltering()!
java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 11:23:48.819: WARN/Filter(16190):     
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter$ArrayFilter.performFiltering(ArrayAdapter.java:437)
04-21 11:23:48.819: WARN/Filter(16190):     
at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
04-21 11:23:48.819: WARN/Filter(16190):     
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 11:23:48.819: WARN/Filter(16190):     
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-21 11:23:48.819: WARN/Filter(16190):     
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I don't really know what's going on here. The nC variable holds the name of the contacts to put into the AutoComplete, so that's not the problem..

Comment: @Elec0: You're absolutely sure nC is not null at this point? Try stepping through the debugger at the autoAdapter line, and just make sure nC is getting passed through correctly (that is, not null).

Comment: I am absolutely sure that it isn't. I tried a Log.e("blah", nC[0]); and it returns the name of a contact.

Comment: Second thought: Where is autoText defined at? Perhaps it is null at this point? Which line does it break on, the 1st or 2nd?

Comment: autoText isn't null, but I did find that some of my nC array is null, but the whole thing isn't. Would that make a difference? If so, how could I remove the null values?

Comment: It probably has something to do with how the contacts are defined that you're reading from.  For instance, did you get the "name"?  What if it's entered as an organization; there will be no name.  It's also possible to save a contact with no name.  I'd look at what data you're getting from Contacts.

Comment: I'm getting the name, yeah, but some of my array has null values, as I said before. I assume that is probably what the problem is. Then my question becomes how do I resize an array to remove the null values?

Comment: How are you populating `nC`? If you're doing it manually, just add a `if(String != "" && String != null)` check before adding it into the array, and use an ArrayList instead so you can add them dynamically. Alternatively, if you're getting the String[] from a method already, you can just make a new list, iterate through the array, and only add non-null values to the ArrayList. ArrayAdapter can take an ArrayList, too, and if the data needs to be changed in any way, it's a more versatile option than a standard array.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot about ArrayLists. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

I've found that problem. It caused by one of my items in arrayadapter have an attribute with 'null' value.

In your case, one of 'nC' elems must be 'null'. Try to show in console a list of all elements like: `System.out.println(index + ": " + nC[index]);` and look up if one of this is null.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Based on information exchanged in comments above: check the data being returned in nC.  Most likely you have a contact with no name.

Answer (score 1):

If he length of nC is 10 by example and you have just 9 elements on it, you will get that exception.

[Source](http://israelwebdev.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/android-spinner-arrayadapter-and-nullpointerexception/)